# jruby war file: How to run rake task present in .war file

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

I am creating war file out of my jruby rails application and deploying on my server. my server contains has only ruby 1.9.3 and glassfish server.

I want to run nightly job in a background using rake task but since my server has only ruby and no rails i didn't find any way to execute rake task on my server.

Please help

Comment: Please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839319/running-rake-task-from-within-war-file it solve your problem

Comment: Thanks.. i will look into it.. just a small question here .. do i need to create jar file for this ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running rake task from within war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839319/running-rake-task-from-within-war-file)